# Two gridView with one scroll in android

Tags: android, gridview

In a activity i need two GridView each of them take as much as it needs as height. No gridview has separate scrollbar but they have only one scrollbar.
I tried something like this.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<GridView
       android:id="@+id/gridView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //as much height as it needs
       android:background="#9C5353"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
       android:numColumns="2"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:scrollbars="none"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       android:verticalSpacing="20dp" >      
       </GridView>


    <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   //as much height as it needs
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried many times but cant get any solution.
Please can anyone have any solution of this??

Comment: Why don't you give margin to second `GridView` ??

Comment: why don't you use only one `RecyclerView` instead ?

Comment: I dont understand what you are talking as i am new to android . @KetanAhir

Comment: I don't know why you use two GridView. If you want to display different data for each GridView then it is also possible with single RecyclerView. Just ask to google for an example.

Comment: Is it possible to use two RecyclerView in one scrollview ? @KetanAhir

Comment: It may be possible but I would not suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the **GridView** Fixed ,and use **ScrollView** include them

```
public class FixedGridView extends GridView {

public FixedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public FixedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public FixedGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

}
```

}

Comment: Where should i put this code ?? is there any complete example ?? @tesla1984

Comment: create a new file FixedGridView into your project, and change the GridView in the layout to the FixedGridView. the FixedGridView is the same as GridView but the FixedGridView will show all the data and have no scrollbar

Comment: Could you provide me a complete example ? @tesla1984

Answer (score 1):

Extending on tesla1984's answer, here is my complete working code.  It works as expected:

- Create a new class named FlexGridView as follows, and save it on a known location inside your project. (I used a folder called "views")

  ```
  package your.project.id.views;

  public class FixedGridView extends GridView {

    public FixedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public FixedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixedGridView(Context context) {
      super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      int expandSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
  }
  ```

Then, on your XML, do something like this:

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <your.product.id.views.FixedGridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewPublic"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="1"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10"
                android:verticalSpacing="10"
                android:background="@color/transparent_color" />
            <your.product.id.views.FixedGridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewPrivate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10"
                android:verticalSpacing="10"
                android:background="@color/transparent_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hey do you have any ideas why implementing the solution above caused gridview.setSelection() not working?